# merge two routes in web api config

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, merge

I have 2 routes in web api config file

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiCtrl",
                                     "api/{controller}/{action}");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi",
                                    "api/{controller}/{id}",
                                    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

when i want to call web apis [GET] like this:

```
/api/contacts/33
```

an error occurs: `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`

how can i merge this two routes and get rid of error?

Solution :

Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing. As the name implies, attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API. For example, you can easily create URIs that describe hierarchies of resources.

Complete Tutorial at [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 1):

This web API seems to work well. Dont think its what you need though?

```
 public static class WebAPIConfig
 {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```